# Erro ao abrir os arquivo do projeto C#

Tags: visual-studio

Ontem a noite eu estava com o Visual Studio aberto com o código fonte da minha aplicação. No entanto, ocorreu uma queda de luz e o computador desligou-se repentinamente.

Logo após ligá-lo novamente, iniciar o Visual Studio e tentar abrir os arquivos deste projeto, a seguinte mensagem ocorre:

> Um ou mais projetos na solução não foram carregados corretamente.
>   Verifique a Janela de Saída para obter detalhes.

E logo na `Janela de Saída`, a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

> C:\Users\Matheus\Desktop\BlueLineTech\BlueLineTech\BlueLineTech.csproj : error  :
>
> Não foi possível carregar o arquivo de projeto. Elemento raiz
>   inexistente. 
>   C:\Users\Matheus\Desktop\BlueLineTech\BlueLineTech\BlueLineTech.csproj

Eu tentei tanto carregar os arquivos do projeto pelo arquivo de `solution` quanto propriamente pelo `BlueLineTech.csproj`, qual é mencionado no aviso da `Janela de Saída`. No entanto, ambos resultam na mesma mensagem de erro.

Acredito que talvez tenha corrompido algo nesse arquivo, não sei ao certo. Existe algo que eu possa fazer ou realmente perdi todo meu código fonte?

Estava trabalhando há dois meses neste projeto, gostaria muito de ajuda quanto a esse problema.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de todos!

Comment: Não, você perdeu apenas o arquivo de projeto nãos o fonte, vá na pasta indica e veja que está todos lá. Claro que se não tinha algo salvo aí perdeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre por algum Arquivo proj corrompido.

Visual Studio sempre guarda um backup desses arquivos em  uma  pasta.

Navegue até:

```
C:\Users\<Seu Usuário>\Documents\Visual Studio <Vs versão>\Backup Files\<seu projeto>
```

você deve ver dois  arquivos como esse:

```
Original-May-18-2018-1209PM.<seu Projeto>.csproj
Recuperado-May-18-2018-1209PM.<seu Projeto>.csproj
```

Copie o seguinte arquivo:

```
Original-May-18-2018-1209PM.<seu Projeto>.csproj
```

e renomeie como

```
<seu projeto>.csproj
```

e coloque na  pasta do  seu  projeto que corrompeu.

Pronto!

Comment: Excelente dica. Muito obrigado, me salvou!